# Tips to upgrade from Rails 2.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to hack around on some open source rails app to learn how a few different features are built in rails, and one in particular I want to use is this:

http://github.com/caffo/colorplan

However, as far as I can tell, this hasn't been upgraded since rails 2.0.2. I would like to upgrade it to Rails 4.0.1 to learn the differences as well as in the end be able to add to the app. Is there an easy way to get this app upgraded, or can someone point me in the right direction to get started on upgrading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whew, this is a biggie.  I haven't done an update from rails 2 in a WHILE, heh so this was kinda fun.  This will ONLY get you started, you'll have a long way to go for after.

First of all, create a new rails 4 app.  Too much of the framework has changed, it will take you hours or days just to get to a place where the app starts, much less works.  So instead, create a new app, and copy the parts of the original app.

** the git commits are done using a global alias to make commits a one liner, you can do it too using:

```
git config --global alias.add-commit '!git add -A && git commit'
```

Step 1 - create the new app:

```
rails new colorplanit4
```

Step 2 - set up a git repository, you'll want to make intermittent commits:

```
cd colorplanit4
git init .
git add-commit -m "Init"
```

Step 3 - cp migrations, app folder, and run db:migrate

```
cp -r ../colorplanit/db/migrate ./db/
rm -rf app
cp -r ../colorplanit/app .
bundle exec rake db:migrate
git add-commit -m "add init migrations & app"
```

Step 4 - update the routes - this may need tweaking but from what I see:

```
Colorplanit4::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'logout', to: 'session#destroy', via: :delete
  get 'login', to: 'session#new'
  match 'register', to: 'users#create', via: :post
  get 'signup', to: 'users#new'

  resources :users
  resource :session
  resources :projects do
    member do
      get :work
      get :pause
      get :importance
      get :archive
    end
    collection do
      get :archived
    end
  end

  resources :users, :sessions
  resource  :session, :controller => 'sessions'
  root to: "projects#index"
  match "about" => "main#about", via: :get
  match "status" => "main#status", via: :get

  get ':controller/:action/:id'
  get ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

end
git add-commit -m "updated routing table"
```

Step 5 - replace before_filter to before_action in **projects_controller.rb**

```
 before_action :login_required
 before_action :age, :only => [:index]·
```

Step 6 - replace application.rb with a new application_controller.rb

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 end
```

That would get the app to a place where it could start.  Then I would strip out the authentication and replace it with devise (just for simplicity)

Best of luck

Comment: :) Thanks! This is a great start to get me going.